# How to integrate Nextjs + styled-components with material-ui

Tags: material-ui, styled-components, next.js

**1.**  To build a next.js app using styled components it's really easy. You just have to use their `_document.js` snippet to enable SSR and prevent styles flickering on page load: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js

**2.** To build a next.js app using material-ui is almost as simple. You just have to start with ther project base: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs, which has its own implementation on `_document.js`: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js

**3.** Sadly, I couldn't figure out how to "merge" both implementations and get a next app where both styled-components and material-ui components can coexist, SSR and do not flicker on page load.

Can you help me?
Is there someone on the internet with better abilities than mine whom already solved that problem but I do not know about?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here, you can find a working example https://github.com/manakuro/nextjs-styled-component-material-ui-example and bog post about it https://javascript.plainenglish.io/ssr-with-next-js-styled-components-and-material-ui-b1e88ac11dfa . This is a common approach, which I also use.

Comment: Here you can also find a good example: [link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/nextjs-with-styled-components-typescript)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Give this a try

**_document.js**

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles';
import theme from '../src/theme';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
    const styledComponentsSheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const materialSheets = new ServerStyleSheets()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
        ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
            enhanceApp: App => props => styledComponentsSheet.collectStyles(materialSheets.collect(<App {...props} />))
          })
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
        return {
          ...initialProps,
          styles: (
            <React.Fragment>
              {initialProps.styles}
              {materialSheets.getStyleElement()}
              {styledComponentsSheet.getStyleElement()}
            </React.Fragment>
          )
        }
      } finally {
        styledComponentsSheet.seal()
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          {/* Use minimum-scale=1 to enable GPU rasterization */}
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"
          />
          {/* PWA primary color */}
          <meta
            name="theme-color"
            content={theme.palette.primary.main}
          />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

**.babelrc**

```json
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}
```

For update check https://github.com/nblthree/nextjs-with-material-ui-and-styled-components

Comment: @alevardi I updated my answer after testing it. Now it works without doubt.

Comment: @alevardi here is a github repo I created https://github.com/MarchWorks/nextjs-with-material-ui-styled-components

Comment: Thank you so much, you are amazing. Works like a charm! :)

Comment: initially I’ve tried the code in here but it didn’t work. then I’ve tried the code in repo, that works well.

Comment: MehmetN.Yarar Yes, since material 4.4 this solution is outdated. Maybe @evgenifotia could update it? That would be amazing, and we will be really thankful.

Comment: @Alevardi if there is anything out of date just open an issue and I will take a look at it and thanks for reporting

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, maybe it was outdated when @MehmetN.Yarar discovered this thread, buy as of right now I just cloned your repo to see what was happening and everything worked just fine. 

Thank you so much for this work!

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me!! I have no idea why some times my styles got rendered correctly and sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone who still has the problem with the code above: I had to also include the StylesProvider in pages/_app.tsx.

_app.tsx:

```
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

<StylesProvider injectFirst>
  {/* Your component tree.
      Now, you can override Material-UI's styles. */}
</StylesProvider>
```

_document.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
          />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          {/* Fonts and icons */}
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons"
          />
          <link
            href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <div id="page-transition" />
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {

  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const materialSheet = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const styledComponentSheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  try {
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
          styledComponentSheet.collectStyles(
            materialSheet.collect(<App {...props} />),
          ),
      });

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return {
      ...initialProps,
      // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
      styles: [
        ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
        materialSheet.getStyleElement(),
        styledComponentSheet.getStyleElement(),
      ],
    };
  } finally {
    styledComponentSheet.seal();
  }
};

export default MyDocument;
```

Comment: This worked for me and feels pretty clean, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This solution works fine for server-side, for client side you also need to change the injection order, as documented here: https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#css-injection-order

To make this work with next.js, you need to change the asignation of the jss constant like this:

```
const jss = create({
  ...jssPreset(),
  insertionPoint: process.browser
    ? window.document.getElementById('jss-insertion-point')
    : null
})
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my `_document.js` file looks like:

```
import Document from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });
      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
}
```

and below find my `.babelrc` file:

```
{ 
  "presets": ["next/babel"], 
  "plugins": [
      ["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed these example approach and worked well for me:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/nextjs-with-styled-components-typescript

Comment: Your example works. But at the same time it has an issue with static builds [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69217739/material-ui-new-v5-0-0-injectfirst-fails-to-set-specificity)