# material ui 'new' v5.0.0 injectFirst fails to set specificity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, styled-components

MUI `v5.0.0` was released today and in my spike branch I am attempting to update to the new version. I'm working through the steps in the mui-docs detailed [here](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#theme). I am using `styled-components` with `NextJS` and it seems that the mui-styles are ***not*** injecting first. I'm not sure what I can do differently to get ahead of this, afaik I've been following everything correctly in that guide and making changes incrementally. Yet, I'm still having the specificity bug.

##### styled-component's style below everything else.

[image]

**`<StylesProvider injectFirst>` doesn't seem to work correctly now**

**Thoughts?**

**_app.tsx**

```js
import styled, { createGlobalStyle, ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import withDarkMode, { useDarkMode } from 'next-dark-mode';
import defaultTheme from 'src/theme';
import TopNavigation from '@components/_molecules/TopNavigation/TopNavigation';
import StyledTypography from '@components/_atoms/Typography/StyledTypography';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StylesProvider } from '@mui/styles';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }): JSX.Element {

  // ? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || (page => page);

  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={setTheme}>
        <RootStyles>
            <PageLayout>
              <TopNavigation />
              <Body>
                {getLayout(
                  <Provider store={store}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                  </Provider>
                )}
              </Body>
              <Footer />
            </PageLayout>
        </RootStyles>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}

const RootStyles = styled.div`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.font.primary};
`;
```

**_document.js**

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@mui/styles';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const styledComponentsSheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const materialSheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props =>
            styledComponentsSheet.collectStyles(
              materialSheets.collect(<App {...props} />)
            ),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {materialSheets.getStyleElement()}
            {styledComponentsSheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      styledComponentsSheet.seal();
    }
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <Head>
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap"
          />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

**package.json**

```
...
 "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.27",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "npm:@mui/styled-engine-sc@latest",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.0",
    "next": "10.2.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "storybook-addon-styled-component-theme": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@mui/styled-engine": "npm:@mui/styled-engine-sc@latest"
  },
...
```

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```js
import StyledEngineProvider from '@mui/material/StyledEngineProvider';

function App() {
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <OtherComponents />
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm using module CSS with a StyledEngineProvider component right now. It works perfectly

Comment: **WORKED** like a charm for me :)

Comment: This did not work like a charm for me

Comment: Saved my day ...i was importing from 
`import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/styled-engine-sc";`

Comment: Do you wrap the component with StyledEngineProvider  or the whole application ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your example it is working correctly, because the inject first is doing his job and injecting the CSS before yours. So all the classes have the same specificity (probably 0.1.0) and in that case, the order matters. So when you "inject first" the default CSS from MUI, then you can overwrite with your custom CSS in classes. I am using CCS Modules in Next 13. Here you have some docs about it.
https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-modules

```
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

export default function YourComponent(){

return (
<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
 <OtherComponents/>
</StyledEngineProvider>
);
}
```

This worked for me. But, it only worked when I used it like this inside the particular component. I tried first creating a global provider wrapping all my app and it did not work.
The problem I was having is that my custom styles written in css modules were overwritten by MUI defaults. Doing this helped change the order of the CSS and having the same specificity, the order is now correct.
Hope this helps!